# Errors installing rgdal in RStudio 1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, anaconda, rstudio

I am using:
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
anaconda-navigator 1.7.0
RStudio 1.1.383

Within the console, I submit

> > install.packages('rgdal')

and get the following:

> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1649449 bytes (1.6 MB)
>   ==================================================
>   downloaded 1.6 MB
>   
>   * installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
>   ** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   configure: CC: /home/name/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
>   configure: CXX: /home/name/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++
>   configure: rgdal: 1.2-16
>   checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
>   configure: svn revision: 701
>   checking for gdal-config... /home/name/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config
>   checking gdal-config usability... yes
>   configure: GDAL: 2.2.2
>   checking GDAL version >= 1.6.3... yes
>   checking gdal: linking with --libs only... no
>   checking gdal: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no
>   ./configure: line 1916: /home/name/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: No such file or directory
>   ./configure: line 1931: /home/name/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: No such file or directory
>   configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
>   configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
>   * removing ‘/home/name/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rgdal’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
>   
>   The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/RtmpIDuQu3/downloaded_packages’
>   Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
>   Making 'packages.html' ... done

I just installed gdal and libgdal, so those should be up to date. How do I fix these errors?

Answer (score 3):

For the record I have the same problem and was because conda.

I did: `conda deactivate` and then install.packages("rgdal") and that works fine. I previously installed the packages mentioned by user50025.

A discussion with a similar problem with units could be find here:
https://github.com/r-quantities/units/issues/223
Everything look like the problem is due to conda who 'is shadowing the system libraries'.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened on me and that was solved with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdal-bin libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

Then try:

```
install.package("rgdal")
```

Comment: Just  to confirm: did you have the same problem using RStudio via Anaconda? The problem for me was rooted in how Anaconda was handling things. I had no problems once I installed RStudio outside Anaconda, and since I'm not using RStudio inside Anaconda, I cannot test your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer over on Dean Attali's blog on setting up an Rstudio server on Ubuntu.

https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/

```
I used the following commands. 

sudo apt-get -y install r-base-dev

sudo apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev

install.packages('rgdal')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses using RStudio via Anaconda.

Comment: With the issues rgdal gives everyone in R this is one way to install it. Feel free to ask to move the comment anywhere else, but rgdal is an issue with R lately.